# Nginx serves static files for admin page but not for my project

Tags: django, docker, nginx

I try to handle that for few days already, and I cannot make it after reading many tutorials docs and questions here. The problem is that my django project, with gunicorn and nginx in docker container does not have static files for my website (404), but it has static files for admin page (which is very strange for me). Here are my configs:

## DJANGO DOCKERFILE

```
FROM python:3

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=memes.settings_prod

RUN mkdir /code

WORKDIR /code

COPY . /code/

RUN pip install -r env_properties/prod/base.txt

RUN pip install -r env_properties/prod/prod.txt

RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput

RUN python manage.py migrate --noinput
```

## NGINX DOCKERFILE

```
FROM nginx

RUN adduser --system --no-create-home --shell /bin/false --group --disabled-login nginx

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install nano -y

COPY env_properties/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

RUN mkdir /code

RUN mkdir /code/static

WORKDIR /code

COPY ./static /code/
```

## NGINX CONFIG

```
location /static {
    autoindex on;
    alias /code/static;
}
```

## DOCKER-COMPOSE

version: '3'

services:

```
web:
  container_name: django_web
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: ./env_properties/prod/Dockerfile
  command: gunicorn -w 4 memes.wsgi:application -b 0.0.0.0:8000
  environment:
    - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=memes.settings_prod
  volumes:
    - .:/code
  ports:
    - '8000:8000'

nginx:
  container_name: nginx_server_2
  command: nginx -g 'daemon off;'
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: env_properties/nginx/Dockerfile
  depends_on:
  - web
  ports:
  - "0.0.0.0:80:80"
  tty: true
```

I go to my pages and at admin page I have
`http://0.0.0.0/static/admin/css/base.css` request URL
which is not present neither at `django_web` or `nginx_server_2` container
(And it loads)

And at my page I have
`http://0.0.0.0/static/memes_apps/style.css` request URL
and `/static/memes_apps/style.css` is present at both django and nginx container

Please tell me what I am doing wrong..

Comment: What are your `STATICFILES_DIRS` and `STATIC_ROOT` settings (used for collectstatic) and where in your Django project are the static files?

Comment: Have a look at [this blog post I wrote](https://www.dedi.co/blog/entries/2018/12/17/deploying-static-files-aws-django-part-1) which explains the various settings and how django static files works.

Comment: STATIC_URL = '/static/'


    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")

Comment: And where are your project's static files stored in your app repository (with respect to BASE_DIR which I assume is the top level of your project, where `manage.py` resides)?

Comment: !(https://imgur.com/8n78tBN)

Comment: Is “memes_apps” a typo in your question? Should be “memes_app”

Comment: FOR MY SAKE, IT WAS TYPO IN HTML TEMPLATE :X thanks anyway...